# jQuery - How to call a function in another scope

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using this: http://terminal.jcubic.pl/

I want to output something, and have that output be a hyperlink that when clicked would output something else.

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $('#terminal').terminal(function(cmd, term) {
             term.echo('\nClick this: <a onClick="javascript:terminal.exec(\'somethingelse\')">somethingelse</a>', {raw: true});
        }, {
            greetings: "Welcome!\n",

            onInit: function(terminal) {
                terminal.echo('Welcome!');
            },
            prompt: '> '
        });
    });
```

However,

```
<a onClick="javascript:terminal.exec
```

doesn't work because terminal.exec isn't defined in the context of the window. What would be the proper way to do it?

Thanks!

Comment: Handle the `onclick` in JavaScript and not inline HTML, and define it where the function is defined in your code.

Comment: It's all within that function:
`$('#terminal').terminal(function(cmd, term) {` so how would that work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define the `onclick` handler in your JavaScript:

```
<!-- In your HTML -->
<a class="trigger-terminal" href="#">Terminal</a>

// In your JavaScript in the scope of terminal
$('.trigger-terminal').click(function() { terminal.exec(); });
```

Or you could sin and expose your `terminal` variable by attaching it to the global `window` object:

```
window.terminal = terminal;
```

Here are the two suggestions inline with your code:

```
// First suggestion

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#terminal').terminal(function(cmd, term) {
         term.echo('\nClick this: <a onClick="javascript:terminal.exec(\'somethingelse\')">somethingelse</a>', {raw: true});
    }, {
        greetings: "Welcome!\n",

        onInit: function(terminal) {
            $('.trigger-terminal').click(function() { terminal.exec(); });

            terminal.echo('Welcome!');
        },
        prompt: '> '
    });

// Second suggestion

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#terminal').terminal(function(cmd, term) {
         term.echo('\nClick this: <a onClick="javascript:terminal.exec(\'somethingelse\')">somethingelse</a>', {raw: true});
    }, {
        greetings: "Welcome!\n",

        onInit: function(terminal) {
            window.terminal = terminal;
            terminal.echo('Welcome!');
        },
        prompt: '> '
    });
});
```

Comment: Neither of those seemed to do anything. There weren't any errors.

Comment: Update has the solutions embedded in the code you provided.

Comment: ```terminal``` is a property of ```$("#terminal");``` it does not exist as a reference itself. IE : ```$('#terminal').terminal``` <-!

Answer (score 0):

Variable can t be access. Also take care that terminal is a property of $('#terminal")

Solution 1

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#terminal').terminal(function(cmd, term) {
         term.echo('\nClick this: '+$('<a></a>').text('somethingelse').on('click', function(){$('#terminal').terminal.exec();}), {raw: true});
    }, {
        greetings: "Welcome!\n",

        onInit: function(terminal) {
            terminal.echo('Welcome!');
        },
        prompt: '> '
    });
});
```

Solution 2

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#terminal').terminal(function(cmd, term) {
         term.echo('\nClick this: <a onClick="javascript:$("#terminal").terminal.exec(\'somethingelse\')">somethingelse</a>', {raw: true});
    }, {
        greetings: "Welcome!\n",

        onInit: function(terminal) {
            terminal.echo('Welcome!');
        },
        prompt: '> '
    });
});
```

wrote on the fly, i hope it is correct. But the idea is there.

Comment: Just so this signature ```$('#terminal').terminal(function(cmd, term) {``` maybe you hsould use term and not terminal, but that is related to your library documentation, right ?